# Error related to assignment and function call

Tags: reactjs

I am converting my html, css and js project to react, everything working fine but when I introduce custom.js file in my project, I am getting the following error:

ERROR in [eslint]
src\assets\js\waypoints.js
Line 29:17:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Line 115:17:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

src\assets\js\waypoints.min.js

Line 10:5578:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Line 10:7557:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error and 2 warnings

```js
<!--line 29 is beginning from line no 4-->
function t(t) {
                var e = this
                this.$element = t, this.element = t[0], this.didResize = !1, this.didScroll = !1, 
                this.id = "context" + c++, this.oldScroll = {
                    x:t.scrollLeft(),
                    y:t.scrollTop()
                }, this.waypoints = {
                    horizontal:{},
                    vertical:{}
                }, t.data(a, this.id),u[this.id] = this, t.bind(v, function() {
                    var t;
                    return e.didScroll || f ? void 0 :(e.didScroll = !0, t = function() {
                        return e.doScroll(), e.didScroll = !1;
                    }, r.setTimeout(t, n[m].settings.scrollThrottle));
                }), t.bind(p, function() {
                    var t;
                    return e.didResize ? void 0 :(e.didResize = !0, t = function() {
                        return n[m]("refresh"), e.didResize = !1;
                    }, r.setTimeout(t, n[m].settings.resizeThrottle));
                });
            }
            
            
<!--line 115 is beginning from line 28  of given code -->
function t(t, e, r) {
                var o, i;
                r = n.extend({}, n.fn[g].defaults, r), "bottom-in-view" === r.offset && (r.offset = function() {
                    var t;
                    return t = n[m]("viewportHeight"), n.isWindow(e.element) || (t = e.$element.height()), 
                    t - n(this).outerHeight();
                }), this.$element = t, this.element = t[0], this.axis = r.horizontal ? "horizontal" :"vertical", 
                this.callback = r.handler, this.context = e, this.enabled = r.enabled, this.id = "waypoints" + y++, 
                this.offset = null, this.options = r, e.waypoints[this.axis][this.id] = this, s[this.axis][this.id] = this, 
                o = null != (i = t.data(w)) ? i :[], o.push(this.id), t.data(w, o);
            }
```

Comment: check your html/jsx part. It may occur occur if you have onClick="" with empty string or variable name , It would be better if you have shared the jsx/html code part